# Does VIM come in distributions for specific purposes like Eclipse or a specialized Linux Distro?

Tags: vim, editor, software-distribution

Vim has alot of plugins, and it's a real versatile time tested text editor.

There are alot of tutorials on the internet on how to configure it for different development purposes and practices using vim plugins.

Eclipse comes in various distros pre-configure for use with various programming languages, and various institutions configure these IDEs and place them out for download on the internet.

Does VIM have a similar site or plugin that will configure vim for use with language X, or for purpose Y?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though there are a couple of so-called Vim "distros" out there (mostly for modern languages like Ruby and PHP), I would recommend against it. In contrast to IDEs like Eclipse, Vim is a highly versatile and configurable editor. If you're unwilling to spend the time to investigate plugins and gradually build your own, personal configuration, Vim may not be the best editor for you. (Or just use it for basic editing tasks in its vanilla installation.)

Don't get me wrong - do look at other people's configuration (many post their .vimrc and configuration, often on GitHub); just don't copy them blindly. With a plugin manager like Pathogen (or just using Vimballs), it's very easy to try and uninstall plugins.

The best source for these is still http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php, though many are also on GitHub, and there's even a GitHub mirror of vim.org at http://vim-scripts.org/, for use with Pathogen.

Comment: I'm willing to put in the effort, it's the lack of time that's got me asking about this...
(oh and cool legos on your site...did you make those?)  Ah you're a c64 guy, very good!